# display an image inside a text field in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

Is it possible to place an image inside `Form::text()` in Laravel? I have tried this:

```
{{ Form::text('Photo', asset('images/img.jpg'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
```

but I get this on my view:

> `http://localhost/HBS/public/images/img.jpg`

Comment: What do mean by image? URL or show the image inside input?

Comment: show the image inside input..

Comment: no, it's not possible